# Duplicate content concerns for directory listings?

Tags: seo, duplicate-content, local-seo, directory-listing

I run a local business directory site with client profile pages structured geographically. I also have a media network to share our listings across other directory sites.

Does having our client page content distributed to a broader media network of sites affect our SEO?

Are their duplicate content concerns with sharing client descriptions with directory sites across the web?

Answer (score 2):

> Does having our client page content distributed to a broader media network of sites affect our SEO?

It can affect SEO positively or negatively depending on how it's done.  Assuming a portion of the data is made available to the network with a link to the full data back to the mothership domain, that would a way to create backlinks and thus improve SEO. However, if any sites on the network are considered spammy, your SEO could suffer.

> Are their duplicate content concerns with sharing client descriptions with directory sites across the web?

Yes. If you are publishing complete and identical listings in multiple sites without appropriate controls (e.g. canonicals) you are potentially creating a problem for yourself.

Comment: Certain content, like client descriptions, are identical across the network...How can I publish to a network of sites, and still retain the SEO value of the unique page content?

Comment: I reference that in my answer. Publish partial content with a link back to your main site.  Partial content won't create duplicate issues and the backlinks raise the profile of the main site.